# Fetching elements of a data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, slice

Given an array of positions, for each row in a data frame. Fetch those elements in the most efficient way without using 'apply' functions.

Here's an example because I'm terrible at explaining. Given this matrix (or data frame):

```
A = matrix(1:9, nrow = 3, ncol = 3)
> A
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    7
[2,]    2    5    8
[3,]    3    6    9
```

Fetch the following elements from each column: 1, 3, 3

That means I want to fetch 1, 8 and 9. The first, third and third elements of each row.

I would expect that A[, c(1,3,3)] would do the trick. But it seems like I need to wrap it up in the diag function.

```
diag(A[, c(1,3,3)])
```

This looks like killing a fly with a nuke. It's extremely inefficient. I know there has to be a simple way to do this (without using apply or any of its family). Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use a matrix of row and column indices to subset a matrix, e.g., `A[cbind(1:3, c(1, 3, 3))]`

Comment: That's it. I was trying A[c(1:3), c(1,3,3)]

Comment: Another inefficient solution `t(A)[c(1, 3, 3) * 1:3]`.